# How to configure Squid

Tags: squid

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my system to use as a server in my office having 50 employees. I have 2 LAN cards in my system:

1. One for input from a BSNL router (192.168.1.250) to my Ubuntu server 
   (192.168.1.1.)
2. Another one from the server (192.168.1.1) to a switch which connects all the employees through squid from that switch via LAN cables.

*How can I configure both LAN cards and squid, as I wants to block some sites and make some restriction on the network.*

Answer (score 0):

You can add needed blocked sites to your blacklist in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`

```
acl     localnet   src    192.168.1.0/24               #define localnet
acl     blacklist dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist"     #define blaclist

http_access deny blacklist
http_access allow localnet
```

in

```
/etc/squid/blacklist
```

List the domains you want to block, starting with '.' to include hostnames/subdomains :

Example:

```
.plaboy.com
.gmail.com
.microsoft.com
.ubuntuforums.org
```

**Note that filtering through a proxy server only works if the browser is configured to use the proxy, and that direct access to the internet is blocked or the user is prevented from modifying the proxy settings of the browser(s)**

Personally if your looking to block just inappropriate website's from use on the computer i would use a network management app like [Parental Control](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) or [Content Filter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/willowng-config-gnome/).

Comment: FWIW: Always tell new admins to whitelist; easier to maintain. Also: his routing issue wasn't addressed: you should tell OP that that is off-topic here (he has a duplicate IP the way he configured his network, so your solution will never work neither as the network won't work anyway)